# Unity 4.5 Sprite Packer does not pack images inside Resources folder

Tags: unity

I'm trying to use the new Sprite Packer tool, but it doesn't work if I put the imagens inside Resouces folder, but inside any other folder it works.

is it a bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All files in the Resources folder exist in your built application (regardless of if they are used). This allows you to load them as needed with `Resources.Load`.

I believe Unity made the decision to prevent files in Resources being built into sprite-sheets because there would be two copies of the same sprite in the built app (which is wasteful).

This answer on the Unity forums uses the same explanation:

http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/248349-Unity-4-5-Sprite-Packer-does-not-pack-images-inside-Resources-folder